# , I need to modify anArray so that all element in the array that have the value of oldVal get replaced with the value of newVal

Tags: javascript

replaceAll function, I need to modify anArray so that all element in the array that have the value of oldVal get replaced with the value of newVal.

Example code

```
let myArray = ["yes", "maybe", "no", "maybe", "yes", "no"];
replaceAll(myArray, "maybe", "no");

function replaceAll() 
{
let oldVal = "";
let newVal = "";
// Need to get input and replace it into the array



}
```

User Input(s) >
anArray (Array)
oldVal (?)
newVal (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way:

```js
let myArray = ["yes", "maybe", "no", "maybe", "yes", "no"];


function replaceAll( arr, oldVal, newVal ) 
  {
  arr.forEach((v,i,a)=>(v===oldVal) && (a[i]=newVal) )
  }

replaceAll(myArray, "maybe", "no");


console.log( myArray )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```